# Run python in server from javascript and get the response

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, ajax

I have a Raspberry that is both server and client.
On the one hand, I have a script in python connected to a fingerprint scanner that scans your fingerprint and responses with the name of the fingerprint owner.

On the other hand, I have a web page where I want to call the mentioned script by clicking a button on javascript.

So, I want to click the button with the id "btn" and execute the script which will scan the fingerprint in the background, and then, when it has finished, will print the name of the person who has identified himself.

I have been reading, and I have seen that this can be done with AJAX, which send the request and get data back to the webpage.

At the moment I have this in my javascript file linked to the button, but this is not working...

```
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");

btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/home/pi/xxx.py",
      data: { param: text}
    }).done(function() {
       // do something
       echo "<p> data </p>"
       x.innerHTML += data
    });
})
```

Can someone help me?
Do I need anything in my python script?

I would be very grateful if it were...

Comment: `data` is not defined at function passed to `.done()`. `echo` is not a JavaScript global function

`.done(function(data) { // define expected parameter `data`
   // do something
   console.log(data);
   x.innerHTML += "<p>" + data + "</p>"
})`